# linear mixed model intrinsic aliasing

Tags: mixed-model, actuarial-science

A bunch of us are studying for an upcoming actuarial exam and none of us understands item II. doesn't result in intrinsic aliasing.

We've calculated the V = ZDZ' +R_1 matrix and as far as we can tell, there's aliasing. But, maybe there's something about this all that we're not understanding.

Linear Mixed Models: A Practical Guide Using Statistical Software (Second Edition) by West et al is the source for this section of the exam, but the question the ASM study manual.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

For those of you having trouble with the images:

II. states that using a compound symmetry structure for the residual in Model 1 would result in intrinsic aliasing.

Model 1's specifications are:
Fixed effects: GRADE, SEX
Random effects: INTERCEPT, SEX for CLASS

In this case study, test scores of students are observed over 4 grades, numbered 0, 1, 2, and 3. There are 70 students in 10 classes. Each student stays in the same class for all 4 grades.

Data Fields:
SCORE - score on the exam (response)
STUDENT - identifier of student
GRADE - grade of the student (0, 1, 2, 3)
SEX - sex of the student (0, 1)
CLASS - Identifier of student's class

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Can you please type the quoted material as text? The font size in the image is so small that I, at least, cannot read it ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen. I can work on typing everything out, but did you try clicking on the images? They get much bigger when you click on them.

Comment: Please type it out.  Clicking on the image will not help on my mobile, and many users use this sites on their phones! Also, you are asking for help from sttangers on the internet, and it is up to you to make it as easy as possible to help!  Also, some blind users use screen-readers, and those do not work with images!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen. Thanks for the additional insight as to why things should be typed out. I typed everything relevant to the question and added it to the original question yesterday, shortly after my comment state that I'd work on do that. Was there something additional you needed to see?

Answer (score 0):

In calculating R_1, do you observe aliasing because sigma^2_int (from the random intercept, call it x^2) and sigma_1 (from the compound symmetric residual cov matrix, call it y) always come out together?

Let's say there are 2 subjects, one male & one female.

Then V = ((1,0),(1,1))*((x^2, cov(int, coef)),(cov(int,coef),sigma^2_coef))*((1,1),(0,1)) + ((sigma^2 + y,y),(y,sigma^2+y))
= ((x^2 + y + sigma^2, x^2 + y + cov(int,coef)),
(x^2 + y + cov(int,coef),x^2 + y + 2*cov(int,coef) + sigma^2_coef + sigma^2))

So, it seems like x^2 and y always appear together. But we estimate parameters for correlation, not covariance, so using cov(int,coef) = cor(int, coef) * x * sigma_coef, by having the random coefficient and this relationship it turns out to no longer lead to intrinsic aliasing, since x now is not a fixed function of the parameter for y.